# TimageList does not contain a member named GetBitmap

Tags: image, listbox, firemonkey, imagelist

I want to load pictures from an `ImageList` to a `TImage` (mobile application, fmx). The TImage is part of my customstyle Listbox (`LBItem.StylesData['myimage']`). The standard approach would be `ImageList.GetBitmap()`. However the GetBitmap method gives me an error: '`TimageList does not contain a member named GetBitmap`'. Any explanation or alternatives? Thanks in advance!

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    i         : Integer;
    LBItem    : TListBoxItem;
    Bitmap : TBitMap;
begin
    ListBox1.BeginUpdate;
    ListBox1.Items.Clear;
    Bitmap := TBitMap.Create;
    try
        for i := 0 to 3 do begin
            LBItem := TListBoxItem.Create(nil);
            LBItem.Parent := ListBox1;
            LBItem.StyleLookup := 'mystyle';
            LBItem.StylesData['mylabel'] := 'Some text...';
            //Bitmap.LoadFromFile('D:\Koala.jpg');
            ImageList1.GetBitmap(i, Bitmap);
            LBItem.StylesData['myimage']:= Bitmap;
        end;
    finally
        ListBox1.EndUpdate;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: "The standard approach would be ImageList.GetBitmap()" why you think so? Did you read documentation http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ImgList.TImageList ?

Comment: Thx for your answer kami, i found that getBitmap exists in vcl but not in fmx. So far I couldn't make my Listbox show the image from my imagelist. Can u help me out here?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have an TImage with name `Image1`, a TImageList with name `ImageList1` and at least one entry in the list with image for scale 1.0 called `Image1Hover`, then you can use the following example to load a "hover picture" in the `OnEnter` event of `Image1`:

```
procedure TForm1.Image1MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item: TCustomBitmapItem;
  Size: TSize;
begin
  ImageList1.BitmapItemByName('Image1Hover', Item, Size);
  Image1.Bitmap := Item.MultiResBitmap.Bitmaps[1.0];
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer is translate from [fire-monkey.ru](http://fire-monkey.ru/topic/2385-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-timagelist/?do=findComment&comment=14133)

Use `ImageList1.Bitmap(Size, Index);`. The `size` is in physical pixels, i.e. we consider the scale independently (this method knows nothing about the scale of the canvas). This function selects the most appropriate size of the image that is available.

So, your code should look something like this:

```pascal
LBItem.StylesData['myimage'] := ImageList1.Bitmap(
  TSizeF.Create(myImageWidth * Canvas.Scale, myImageHeight * Canvas.Scale), 
  i);
// Not sure of the correctness of this assignment to 'myimage'
```

**Note 1** All the bitmaps obtained in the 'ImageList1.Bitmap` are stored in the imagelist cache. So don't release them.

**Note 2** ListBox has internal mechanism to interact with ImageList. Try to use `icon: TImage` style item and `LBItem.ImageIndex` property, without load bitmaps.

Answer (score 2):

In **FMX** you don't need any additional coding for that, just use `TGlyph` instead of `TImage` if you want to display images directly form `ImageList`.

example :

```
Glyph1.ImageIndex := i;
```

Comment: You're a hero my friend.

Comment: great solution unless you want a stretched image in which case the first answer applies. i guess TGlyph only displays proportional images despite the `stretch` property.